# Integral with modified Bessel functions of the first and second kind

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions, elliptic-integrals

Consider the following integral
$$I\left(a, b\right)=\int\limits _0^{+\infty}\cos\left(x\right)I_1\left(ax\right)K_1\left(bx\right)dx,$$
where $a$ and $b$ are parameters such that $b\geq a \geq 0$, and $I_\nu\left(x\right)$ and $K_\nu\left(x\right)$ are the modified Bessel functions of the first and second kind, respectively.

Is it possible to express this integral in terms of elementary and basic special functions?

[Similar issue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413530/definite-integral-with-modified-bessel-functions-of-first-and-second-kind) has already been addressed; the result involves complete elliptic integrals.

Comment: I tried $a=b=1$ and WA also gives an answer in terms of complete elliptic integrals, so seems that you're in luck. Although considering the lengthy solution in the linked answer, this one is not going to be easy either

Comment: @YuriyS. I tried to make $b=a+\epsilon$ and expand around $\epsilon=0$ but no way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_0^{\infty } \cos (x) I_1(a x) K_1(b x) \, dx=\frac{Q_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{a^2+b^2+1}{2 a b}\right)}{2 \sqrt{a b}}$$

where:$Q_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{a^2+b^2+1}{2 a b}\right)$ is  Legendre Q Function.

from Book: [Table of Integrals, Series, and Products 8th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123849330) on page: 726 in: `6.672.4`

Answer (score 3):

For $a=b>0$, a CAS produces
$$I(a,a)=\frac{\left(2 a^2+1\right) K\left(-4 a^2\right)-E\left(-4 a^2\right)}{2 a^2}$$